# How to get cell value by column name and row number

Tags: php, phpexcel

Imagine an Excel file with 2 columns like below:

```
Name    Surname
John    Some surname
Matt    Another surname
Steve   Again something
```

Is there a way to get a value of the cell by column name and row number? Something like this:

```
$worksheet->getCellByColumnNameAndRowValue('Name', 1)->getValue(); // gives John
```

Right now I'm using an array that maps column names to column numbers and `getCellByColumnAndRow` function but I wonder if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, because 'Name' is just a string cell value (the value in cell 'A1') to PHPExcel, it isn't a column name (that would be column 'A')

What you could do would be to specify a Named Range called 'Name' (or 'Surname', or whatever)... then you could use the namedRangeToArray() method to return the values of all cells in the named range as an array.

Comment: So `namedRangeToArray('Name')` in my case would return an array (0 => John, 1 => Matt, 2 => Steve)?

Comment: Ok, so still I need to map column name to range (in my case columns change their place frequently) - I will stick with my original solution then.

Comment: Unless defined as a named range, PHPExcel is simply a file reader/writer for Excel files.... accessing data via column name, row where column name is a cell label requires "interpretation" of the data in the worksheet, which is rather more than simply reading/writing.... so "mapping" is up to your scripts